# Undefined function 'mid' in expression in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to write a query in MS Access, and receiving the error "Undefined function 'mid' in expression' when I try to execute it.

```
SELECT MID([ColumnName], 4,2)
FROM tblName
```

As I understand it, the MID function is the MS Access equivalent to Substring. Both the table and the column definitely exist.  What could be causing this error?

Comment: You might received this error because ColumnName doesn't exist

Comment: Check 'References'  in 'Tolls' menu in VBA, there must not be some 'MISSING' libraries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check 'References' in 'Tools' menu in VBA, there must be some 'MISSING' libraries.

Comment: That was it.  Would you recommend deleting all references in a database without any reports or forms or just the one that is "Missing"?

Comment: There are 2 system's references("Visual Basic for applications" and "Microsoft Access ??? Object Library") that couldn`t be deleted, all others can be deleted if you don't use functions from them.