# weird issue with SQL query in MS Access (Office 365)

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016, mssql-jdbc

I have recently inherited a process that requires running queries in MS Access database. Yesterday I stumbled upon the following weird issue, which I can not logically explain:

1. The query does not run in the latest version of the database file (August 2021 data)

- Error message: "undefined VAL() function". When I remove VAL(), a new error message appears: "undefined MID() function"; the messages do not make any sense, as both functions are used in MS SQL.

2. The same query ran fine in the earlier (May 2021) version of the database, which I downloaded from the corporate server (backup copy, available through "previous versions")

- when I copy the query from May database to Aug database, I receive error messages as in "1" (above).

3. When I copy data from Aug file into May file, the query runs fine. This makes me think that the problem is not a data issue.

I am not sure if the person who produced the reporting before me has done something with August file, or whether this is a weird computer glitch...

I know how to fix the problem (i.e. by copying data from August database to May database), but I am at a loss as to the cause of the error. Any assistance will be highly appreciated!

---

SQL Query Code (converts USD to CAD):

```
UPDATE T1_DEF_EXPENSETYPE_COST AS F1, SM_FX_MAVG AS F2 SET F1.CDE = F1.COA *  IIF( CURRENCY_TYPE = 'CAD',1, 
                              IIF(MID(F1.PERIOD,10,2) = '01',F2.[M12],0) + 
                              IIF(MID(F1.PERIOD,10,2) = '02',F2.[M01],0) + 
                              IIF(MID(F1.PERIOD,10,2) = '03',F2.[M02],0) + 
                              IIF(MID(F1.PERIOD,10,2) = '04',F2.[M03],0) + 
                              IIF(MID(F1.PERIOD,10,2) = '05',F2.[M04],0) + 
                              IIF(MID(F1.PERIOD,10,2) = '06',F2.[M05],0) + 
                              IIF(MID(F1.PERIOD,10,2) = '07',F2.[M06],0) + 
                              IIF(MID(F1.PERIOD,10,2) = '08',F2.[M07],0) + 
                              IIF(MID(F1.PERIOD,10,2) = '09',F2.[M08],0) + 
                              IIF(MID(F1.PERIOD,10,2) = '10',F2.[M09],0) + 
                              IIF(MID(F1.PERIOD,10,2) = '11',F2.[M10],0) + 
                              IIF(MID(F1.PERIOD,10,2) = '12',F2.[M11],0)), F1.FX_PERIOD = MID(F2.PERIOD,4,4) & 
                              IIF(MID(F1.PERIOD,10,2) = '01','-M12','') & 
                              IIF(MID(F1.PERIOD,10,2) = '02','-M01','') & 
                              IIF(MID(F1.PERIOD,10,2) = '03','-M02','') & 
                              IIF(MID(F1.PERIOD,10,2) = '04','-M03','') & 
                              IIF(MID(F1.PERIOD,10,2) = '05','-M04','') & 
                              IIF(MID(F1.PERIOD,10,2) = '06','-M05','') & 
                              IIF(MID(F1.PERIOD,10,2) = '07','-M06','') & 
                              IIF(MID(F1.PERIOD,10,2) = '08','-M07','') & 
                              IIF(MID(F1.PERIOD,10,2) = '09','-M08','') & 
                              IIF(MID(F1.PERIOD,10,2) = '10','-M09','') & 
                              IIF(MID(F1.PERIOD,10,2) = '11','-M10','') & 
                              IIF(MID(F1.PERIOD,10,2) = '12','-M11',''), F1.FX_Rate = IIF( CURRENCY_TYPE = 'CAD',1, 
                              IIF(MID(F1.PERIOD,10,2) = '01',F2.[M12],0) + 
                              IIF(MID(F1.PERIOD,10,2) = '02',F2.[M01],0) + 
                              IIF(MID(F1.PERIOD,10,2) = '03',F2.[M02],0) + 
                              IIF(MID(F1.PERIOD,10,2) = '04',F2.[M03],0) + 
                              IIF(MID(F1.PERIOD,10,2) = '05',F2.[M04],0) + 
                              IIF(MID(F1.PERIOD,10,2) = '06',F2.[M05],0) + 
                              IIF(MID(F1.PERIOD,10,2) = '07',F2.[M06],0) + 
                              IIF(MID(F1.PERIOD,10,2) = '08',F2.[M07],0) + 
                              IIF(MID(F1.PERIOD,10,2) = '09',F2.[M08],0) + 
                              IIF(MID(F1.PERIOD,10,2) = '10',F2.[M09],0) + 
                              IIF(MID(F1.PERIOD,10,2) = '11',F2.[M10],0) + 
                              IIF(MID(F1.PERIOD,10,2) = '12',F2.[M11],0))
WHERE F1.COA IS NOT NULL AND 
          VAL(MID(F1.PERIOD,4,4)) = VAL(MID(F2.PERIOD,4,4)) + VAL(IIF(MID(F1.PERIOD,10,2) = '01',1,0))  AND 
          F2.BASE_RATE = 'CAD' AND F2.CURRENCY_CODE = 'USD';
```

Comment: Just for the record `sql server` does not equal `access`. `mssql` or `sql server` is an RDBMS that is very different from Microsoft Access and it's sql dialect.

Comment: Is that the full error message you are receiving when you try to run this in your August version of your access database?

Comment: The exact message is as following: " Undefined function 'MID' in expression " . The message does not make sense, as the query runs well when I copy data from Aug file into May database.

Comment: Interesting. Suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29153696/undefined-function-mid-in-expression-in-ms-access/29169482) states to check references made in VBA-"Tools" menu and deselecting any missing references. Strange error to surface in such an occasion though.

Comment: Checked library references, and found that them to be identical in both Aug and May files. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Sometimes weirdness is due to corruption and the cause will never be determined. Try downloading the file again and see if issue replicates. If it does, then stick with the solution you have - transferring data to another file. Why is monthly data in different files anyway? Why the mssql-jdbc tag?

Comment: To clarify, I am not interested in the most obvious solution (transfer data to the old file). What I would like is to understand how the individual who transferred the reporting process to me managed to corrupt (the latest version of) database file in such way that no queries could be run. This is the second time this happened, and I would like to understand how to handle this issue.